# get the size of dataset after applying a filter from tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can I get the size or the len of the dataset after applying a filter. Using tf.data.experimental.cardinality give -2, and this is not what I am looking for!! I want to know how many filtered samples exist in my dataset in order to be able to split it to training and validation datasets using take() and skip().

Example:

```py
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    dataset = dataset.filter(lambda x: x < 4)
    size = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(dataset).numpy()
    #size here is equal to -2 but I want to get the real size which is 3
```

My dataset contains images and their labels, this is just an illustrative example

Comment: If it is just a one time operation and the dataset size is not huge, you can use `len(list(dataset))`.

Comment: Actually the dataset is huge, and I tried it but it took a long time (couldn't get the results because I had to stop the script)